# How to generate $X$ uniform on $\{0,...9\}$ from $Y$ uniform on $\{0,...,7\}$

Tags: probability-theory, random, simulation

Assume I have a random integer in the range form 0 to 7 and I want to generate a random integer from 0 to 9, how would I go about doing so?

I though about doing the following: First I choose a random number from 0 to 7. Then I reduce this number mod 2. Then I can choose one of the sets $\{0,...4\}$ and $\{5,...,9\}$, so the problem is reduced to choosing a random number from 0 to 4. Now one can choose random numbers from 0 to 7 until one lies between 0 an 4.

Unfortunately the above method does not necessarily terminate(although it terminates with prbability 1), so I was wondering about a method that guarantees me to terminate after a finite numer of steps.

Also I was wondering more generally if there is a strategy to transform a random variable that is equally distributed between $0$ and $n$ into a random variable that is equally distributed between $0$ and $m$.
I think one can extend the above strategy to reduce the problem to find a random variable equally distributed between $0$ and $(m+1)/gcd(n+1,m+1)-1$ but in generally(for example if $n+1$ and $m+1$ are both prime) this is not really helpfull.

Comment: Use $X$, sampled repeatedly, to construct a uniform random number in $[0,1]$, call it $\bar X$.  Then let $Y=0$ if $0≤\bar X<\frac 18$ and so on.  With probability $1$ you only need finitely many draws of $X$ to specify $Y$.

Comment: If you need to guarantee a result after a specific number of samples, sample $X$ three times, giving you $1000=8\times 125$ equi-probable variables.  Partition these into $8$ equal classes.  Of course this only works because it happens that $8$ divides $10^n$ for suitable $n$.

Comment: I you sample X three times you get 8^3 different results. In particular that is not divisible by 10.

Comment: I was going from $X$ to $Y$ (in error).  My calculation is, I think, correct but it's the opposite of what the OP actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

When $|Y|$ has prime factors that aren't prime factors of $|X|$ you can't transform a uniform distribution on $X$ to a uniform distribution of $Y$.

It's a simple fact that many people doesn't realise.

The simplest case, that I have succesfully used to convince people (unfortunately not all) is: Imagine that you have to decide if your new car should be red, green or blue and all you have is a coin - no matter what strategy (that gives an equal distribution) you use for mapping the result of a series of coin flips there will always be a chance that you flip a sequence that doesn't map to any of the choices.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but do you have a proof for this claim? I guess you mean that the series of coin flips is bounded? Otherwise you can always do rejection sampling right?

Answer (score 1):

Generating a random variable uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X=\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ from a random variable uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y=\{0,1,\ldots,7\}$ is obviously impossible since the latter yields $|\mathfrak Y|=8$ cases while one needs $|\mathfrak X|=10$ cases.

Thus, let us assume that the question is actually asking whether there exists some integer $n$ such that one can generate a random variable uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X$ from an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ uniform on $\mathfrak Y$. Such a sample is equivalent to a single random variable uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y^n$, whose size is $|\mathfrak Y^n|=8^n$, hence one is asking for a partition of a set of size $8^n$ into $10$ subsets of equal sizes. But $8^n$ is not a multiple of $10$ hence such a partition does not exist.

---

**Edit:** To generate several i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X$ from a random, non bounded, number of i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y$, one can exploit the fact that $8^{10}=1073741824$ is only slightly larger than $10^9$, to devise a somewhat efficient rejection sampling algorithm.

Thus, one first simulate a sample $(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_{10})$ of size $10$ uniform on $\mathfrak Y$, then one encodes it as a single integer $Z=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{10}8^{k-1}Y_k$, uniformly distributed on $\{0,1,\ldots,8^{10}-1\}$.

- If $Z\leqslant10^9-1$, the $9$ digits of $Z$ yield a sample of size $9$ uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X$.
- If $10^9\leqslant Z\leqslant8^{10}-1$, one forgets $Z$ and one restarts with a new sample of size $10$ uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y$.

This produces $9$ values uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X$ from a sample of $10$ values uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y$, with probability of success $p=10^9/8^{10}$, thus, if one repeats the procedure, each random variable uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak X$ uses $10/(9p)$ random variables uniformly distributed on $\mathfrak Y$, for a mean efficiency of $9p/10\approx83.8\%$. Choosing longer strings of $\mathfrak Y$-samples, one can attain every efficiency smaller than the theoretical maximum efficiency $9/10=90\%$.

Comment: @downvoter Any explanation for your vote, or are you merely practicing the "art" of silent retaliation?

Comment: A second @downvoter seems to be having fun.

Comment: And a third one, as silent as the others, and as motivated by the maths, surely... This is more and more amusing.

Comment: +1 of course, but you are really asking for downvotes by commenting in response to each one!

Comment: @aduh Thanks. The side effect you are mentioning does not bother me, actually, this is simply pushing a psychological experiment as far as possible, in a way.